# Looking to have my bot receive a message, and convert letters with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, replace, mapping, discord.js

So i wanna be able to do something like “~~lofitext message” and then it’ll send back “ｍｅｓｓａａｇｅ” with Discord.js. Basically convert each letter to the special character version. Is there any way to do that? Maybe with mapping or some kind of array?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by special characters, but we can swap all characters with Latin characters.

```
const latin_chars = {
  a: 'A\u0301',
  b: 'B\u0301',
  c: 'C\u0301',
};

var msg = 'abc';
// split + map
var msg_converted1 = '';
msg.split('').map(c => {
    msg_converted1 += latin_chars[c];
});
// for loop
var msg_converted2 = '';
for(let i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
    msg_converted2 += latin_chars[msg[i]];
}

// for/in
var msg_converted3 = '';
for(c in msg) {
    msg_converted3 += latin_chars[msg[c]];
}

console.log(msg_converted1);
console.log(msg_converted2);
console.log(msg_converted3);
```